python, chat_id = update['message']['chat']['id'] KeyError: 'message'
я не использую никаких модулей для телеграмма, так сказать хардкор)
chat_id = update['message']['chat']['id']
         ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
Key Error: 'message'


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Удачи в вашем превозмогании

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!  рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

В некоторых апдейтах нет объекта message потому, что не все апдейты связанны с сообщением, это например когда кто-то поставил реакцию сообщению.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
